# Jquery .waypoint not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the next code, what i need is when scrolling down reaches the class .ua, to show the alert. But nothing is happening. I also checked the route of script and stuff like .addClass works perfectly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.ua').waypoint(function() {
    alert('Top of header hit top of viewport.');
 });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>First one</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="main-nav">
  
 </nav>
 <div class="main-div">
  
 </div>
 <div class="ua">
  <h1>HOLAA</h1>
 </div>
<script src="jq/jq.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `waypoint()` isn't a native jQuery function... use e.g. (https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use a plug-in. Look how easy this is:

```js
pastit = false;
wayloc = $('.ua').position().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
  pos = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('#msg').html(pos); //UNNECESSARY - For Demo Only
  if ( !pastit && pos > 500){
    pastit = true;
    $('body').css('background','palegreen');
  }else if (pastit && pos < 500){
    pastit = false;
        $('body').css('background','white');
  }
});

// Necessary for stack snippets window to work Full Screen
$(window).resize(function(){
  wayloc = $('.ua').position().top;
});
```

```css
html,body{min-height:2000px;}
.main-nav{width:100vw;height:250px;}
.main-div{width:100vw;height:500px;}
.ua {width:100vw;height:30px;background:wheat;border:1px solid orange;}

/* Unnecessary - For Demo Only */
#msg{position:fixed;top:50px;left:70%;padding:10px;min-width:50px;text-align:center;background:wheat;border:1px solid orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="msg"></div><!-- Unnecessary For Demo Only-->

<nav class="main-nav"></nav>
<div class="main-div"></div>

<div class="ua">
  <h1>HOLAA</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to include waypoints jQuery plugin just before the ending `head` tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.0/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 $('.ua').waypoint(function() {
    alert('Top of header hit top of viewport.');
 });

});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/grid.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.0/jquery.waypoints.js"></script>

 <nav class="main-nav">
  
 </nav>
 <div class="main-div">
  
 </div>
 <div class="ua">
  <h1>HOLAA</h1>
 </div>
<script src="jq/jq.js"></script>
```